# Why this four lines code gives 0.45<0.45 is True

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

python code:

```
x=0.35
while (x<0.45):
    x=x+0.05
    print x,"<",0.45, x<0.45
```

below is the output:

```
0.4 < 0.45 True
0.45 < 0.45 True
0.5 < 0.45 False
```

Why 0.45<0.45 is true?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Floating point problems, look them up. Floats are **not** exact representations.

Comment: this is a general computing problem and is found in other languages too, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're actually comparing:

```
0.44999999999999996 < 0.45
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> x=0.35
>>> while (x<0.45):
        x = x+0.05
        print repr(x),"<",0.45, x<0.45
...     
0.39999999999999997 < 0.45 True
0.44999999999999996 < 0.45 True
0.49999999999999994 < 0.45 False
```

`print` calls `str` on floats, which prints a human friendly version:

```
>>> print 0.44999999999999996
0.45
>>> print str(0.44999999999999996)
0.45
>>> print repr(0.44999999999999996)
0.44999999999999996
```

Comment: @user62367 It's not related to python, read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is called floating point error. It arises from the fact that you want to represent infinite amount of numbers with finite amount of bytes. So adding one floating point number with another will result in a floating point number that might be just close to the actual mathematical result. "Just close" might mean deviation of 0.0000001 or so to the expected result. You can read more about floating point errors here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980